# How to hide 'Extensions' icon in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome has recently started showing an 'Extensions' icon (like [image: Google Chrome Extensions Icon]) next to the address bar. Other extensions icons can be hidden (or unpinned) from the Chrome but not this icon. Any idea how it can be unpinned/hidden/removed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Type below-mentioned string in the address bar.

> chrome://flags/#extensions-toolbar-menu

2. Change "Extensions Toolbar Menu" settings from 'Default' to 'Disabled'.

You need to relaunch the browser once for this to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the flag has just been removed in 87.0.4280.66.
Please write a comment here so that the developers can see your opinion:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139681&q=hide%20extensions%20icon&can=2