# How to hide 'Extensions' from the Extensions' icon/toolbar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

CURRENT CHROME VERSION: Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Google recently has added the new Zigsaw Puzzle in the toolbar icon on the top right hand side of the Google Chrome. Furthermore, it cannot be disabled like it used to be due to recent updates by the previous method which is given in this link -> ["how-to-hide-extensions-icon-in-google-chrome ?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1558474/how-to-hide-extensions-icon-in-google-chrome)

Since we can already access the extensions' menu given in 'More Tools' by pressing the 3 vertical dots in the toolbar of Google Chrome (given in the top right hand side) and change the settings as desired; I want to hide some of the already existing extensions from the toolbar/extension-icon's (Zigsaw Puzzle's) drop-down list while they are in use as they could previously be done in the older versions as stated in the following to unhide the extension -> ["how-to-unhide-an-extension-in-chrome ?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1523164/how-to-unhide-an-extension-in-chrome)

This will make it difficult for the non-administrative user to alter/change the extensions and their settings according to their own will.

Screenshot for easy reference has been given below. Please note that I don't wish to see the extensions in the toolbar also in case the extension's icon is made to disappear.
[image]

Alternatively, if the above cannot be done, is there a way to completely disable the entire toolbar in Google Chrome? A similar method to disable the incognito mode by Windows Registry has been used and reference is given here: ["how-to-disable-incognito-mode-in-chrome ?"](https://advyon.com/how-to-disable-incognito-mode-in-chrome/)